# Are some of the musicians actual musicians?

Tags: mozart-in-the-jungle

In Mozart in the Jungle, are some of the New York Orchestra actual musicians or are they all actors? It always seems to me that it would be too difficult to mimic playing complex instruments effectively, so I wonder if they use real musicians.

Answer (score 2):

In [This interview](http://www.indiewire.com/article/gael-garcia-bernal-on-what-mozart-in-the-jungle-taught-him-and-the-color-and-scope-of-season-2-20151229) with Gael García Bernal, he talks about how hard it was for the actors to pretend they're playing instruments, saying:

> I think for all of us there's two who have had the most difficult job, which is Joel [Bernstein] and Saffron [Burrows]. Joel playing the violin and Saffron playing the cello. Because the cello is pretty big. You know, it's very graphic. You see the bow. You have to follow it the way everybody else is doing it. And if you look at somebody's face you see where their hand is standing. So, you can really tell how they're grabbing the strings here and the bow.

But then later on when the interviewer asks about a "jam session" with some of the actors he says:

> I mean the thing is, sometimes we can play the music that we're playing because there's real musicians in the orchestra. So, sometimes it's like, "Okay. Should we go for it?"

The implication I think, is that the main characters are just actors, but as for the others in the orchestra real musicians were hired to keep up the illusion of a real orchestra.